# Not able to get any data from client post request in c++ microhttpd Server

Tags: c++, httpserver

```
#include <microhttpd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
class CHttpServer
{
private:
    /* Port : A unique identifier for application */
    int m_port;
    /* MHD_Daemon : It represents a running instance of HTTP Server
       when  we start HTTP server using MHD_start_daemon() then
       it returns a pointer to MHD_Demon object */
    struct MHD_Daemon *m_daemon;

public:
    /* Constructor function for HTTP Server */
    CHttpServer(int port);

    /* start() function is used to start HTTP Server and waiting for listening incoming requests from clients */
    bool start();

    /* stop() function will stops running http server */`your text`
    void stop();

    /* Callback function : which will handle http requests */

    static int requestHandler(void *cls, struct MHD_Connection *connection,
                              const char *url, const char *method,
                              const char *version, const char *upload_data,
                              size_t *upload_data_size, void **con_cls);
};

/*************************HttpServer.cpp********************************/
#include "HttpServer.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/* Implementation of constructor function */
CHttpServer::CHttpServer(int port)
{
    this->m_port = port;
    this->m_daemon = nullptr;
}

/* Implementation of start()  function  */
bool CHttpServer::start()
{
    m_daemon =
        MHD_start_daemon(MHD_USE_SELECT_INTERNALLY, m_port, nullptr, nullptr,
                         &requestHandler, nullptr, MHD_OPTION_END);
    return m_daemon != nullptr;
}

/* Implementation of stop() */
void CHttpServer::stop()
{
    if (m_daemon != nullptr)
    {
        MHD_stop_daemon(m_daemon);
        m_daemon = nullptr;
    }
}

int post_data_iterator(void *cls, enum MHD_ValueKind kind, const char *key,
                       const char *value)
{
    std::cout << "post_data_iterator called" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Kind: " << kind << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;

    std::string *requestData = static_cast<std::string *>(cls);
    if (kind == MHD_POSTDATA_KIND)
    {
        if (value != nullptr)
        {
            requestData->append(value);
        }
    }
    cout << *requestData << endl;
    return MHD_YES;
}

/* Implementation of requestHandler() function */
int CHttpServer::requestHandler(void *cls, struct MHD_Connection *connection,
                                const char *url, const char *method,
                                const char *version, const char *upload_data,
                                size_t *upload_data_size, void **con_cls)
{
    /* Handle Options Method */
    if (strcmp(method, "OPTIONS") == 0)
    {
        const char *response_data = "";

        struct MHD_Response *response =
            MHD_create_response_from_data(strlen(response_data),
                                          (void *)response_data, MHD_NO,
                                          MHD_NO);

        MHD_add_response_header(response, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        MHD_add_response_header(response, "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                                "POST");

        MHD_add_response_header(response, "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                                "Content-Type");

        int ret = MHD_queue_response(connection, MHD_HTTP_OK, response);

        MHD_destroy_response(response);

        return ret;
    }
    /* Post request * */
    if (strcmp(method, "POST") == 0)
    {
        std::string requestData;

        // MHD_get_connection_values(connection, MHD_POSTDATA_KIND, post_data_iterator, &requestData);
        cout << endl
             << "post Data size : " << *upload_data_size << endl;
        if (*upload_data_size > 0)
        {
            requestData.append(upload_data, *upload_data_size);
            *upload_data_size = 0;
        }

        std::cout << endl
                  << "Post Request Data: " << requestData << std::endl;

        const char *response_data = "OK";
        struct MHD_Response *response =
            MHD_create_response_from_data(strlen(response_data),
                                          (void *)response_data, MHD_NO,
                                          MHD_NO);
        MHD_add_response_header(response, "Content-Type", "text/plain");
        MHD_add_response_header(response, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        int ret = MHD_queue_response(connection, MHD_HTTP_OK, response);

        MHD_destroy_response(response);

        return ret;
    }

    return MHD_NO;
}

/**********************main.cpp*****************************/
#include "HttpServer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int port = 8000;
    CHttpServer server(port);

    bool ret = server.start();
    if (ret == 0)
    {
        cout << "Failed to start HTTP Server!!";
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "\nHTTP Server running on port : " << port;

    cout << "\nPress Enter to stop Server !";
    cin.get();

    server.stop();
    cout << "\nHTTP Server stopped !!";
    return 0;
}
```

I want to get the data from post request made by browser.
I am getting length of upload_data as 0 , please help me to resolve it
The client is written on JavaScript and is making a ajax call but not able to get that post request in server side , suggest me changes in my code

The upload_data or requestData is always coming out to be null

Comment: OT: Please get out of the habit of leading newlines when printing. If `std::cout` is tied to the C stream `std::stdout` (the default) and you're running from an interactive terminal, then a newline will flush the output. If you have a leading newline, you flush (actually write) the *previous* line, while the current might not be printed. That could lead to the output not matching the state of your program.